# How to use spring boot security for custom login page without configuration?

Tags: java, session, spring-boot, spring-security

I am using spring security on spring boot app and I cannot use the custom login page I made. I want to use custom login page by default without using configuration controller, instead I want to change configuration from application.properties. Also I want to deny access to other pages until login successful. Please help me to log out of the application.

Comment: I don't have config and i am asking that i want to use custom login page without config or using application.properties file for configuration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Spring Security Reference provides an [extensive guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.2.RELEASE/guides/html5/form-javaconfig.html) on how to implement your custom login page.

I put together a small example in [this repo](https://bitbucket.org/poear/custom-login-page/src)

Comment: Do we need to use WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class on. Can't we use application.properties instead of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class?

Comment: There is no way to accomplish this solely with `application.properties` **that I'm aware of**, I doubt there is.

And the approach that I suggested is the recommended way by the spring team.

Comment: thanks for the customlogin.html example, I was using wrong login html file and lost whole day because of that

Answer (score 1):

[Spring Security With Customn login Page](https://github.com/tahermahodia/Spring3HibernateIntegration)

An example of spring security with custom login page is provided along with that sitemash+hibernate is also implemented you have to create a database dumb is given in the readme file.